# don't install symfony/console v5.0.5 \ankitpokhrel/tus-php in laravel 7

Tags: tus

I am facing this issue of `don't install symfony/console v5.0.5` Using version ^1.2 for ankitpokhrel/tus-php in laravel 7 version. Please help me out. Im not getting how to resolve it...

**This is the screenshot of my issue**
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your ```composer.json``` file.

Answer (score 1):

i found answer for this isuue...`composer require ankitpokhrel/tus-php:dev-symfony-5` ......goto this link[i found help here](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/tus-php/issues/245)